# Por que recebo este Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c

Por que quando declaro:

```
char *s = "string";

fscanf(stdin, "%s", s);
```

Recebo um Segmentation Fault?

Comment: Você está tentando gravar algo na std**in**; não seria pro std**out** que você deveria mandar a string?

Answer (score 5):

O código abaixo tem os seguintes problemas:

```
char *s = "string";
sprintf(stdin, "%s", s);
```

- `stdin` é do tipo `FILE *`, e o primeiro parâmetro de `sprintf` é uma variável do tipo `char *`. Não misture os tipos, ou o resultado é indefinido. Para escrever para `FILE *`, use `fprintf`.
- Você pode ler da **entrada** padrão; se você quiser *escrever*, você deve usar a **saída** padrão.

O código abaixo faz o que (eu acho que) você quer.

```
void main() {
    char *s = "string";
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", s);
}
```

**[Mais detalhes depois da edição da pergunta]** Para o código abaixo:

```
char *s = "string";
fscanf(stdin, "%s", s);
```

Quando você declara uma string literal em um programa em C, o compilador geralmente (*) define essas literais em endereços de memória que são *read-only*; então se você tenta modificá-lo, o programa irá levantar uma *segmentation fault*. Se você quiser evitar isso, você pode ou declarar a variável na pilha (e.g., `char s[20] = "string";`) ou no *heap* (e.g., `char *s = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); strcpy(s, "string");`. (**)

(*) Isso é dependente da plataforma; em algumas plataformas / compiladores, o seu código pode funcionar sem problemas, mas você não deve contar com isso.

(**) O uso das funções de scanf para string são perigosas, considere usar funções que limitem o número de caracteres lidos para que não tenha perigo de buffer overflows.